# React: How to get values from Material-UI TextField components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a small app with a Form component, a SubmitButton component, and my parent (App.js) component. When the user clicks the submit button I want to get the values of the 3 fields on my form component and pass them to my App.js component. I am not sure how to trigger the event using `onClick()` or something like it to grab the form field values from my form and then pass them via `props` to the App.js component and `console.log()` them. Can anyone provide some guidance as I am very new to React?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'
import Form from './Components/InfoForm'
import SubmitButton from './Components/SubmitButton';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Checkbox from './Components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkbox: false,
});

const handleChange = event => {
  setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};

  return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />             
     <Form />
     <Checkbox name="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} checked={state.checkbox} />
     <SubmitButton isEnabled={state.checkbox} onClick={} /> 
     </Container>     
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**InfoForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

function Form() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    months: ''
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (

    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.name}
        onChange={handleChange('name')}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
      />

      <TextField
        id="outlined-email-input"
        label="Email"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.email}
        type="email"
        name="email"
        autoComplete="email"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
      />      

      <TextField
        id="outlined-select-months"
        select
        label="Select"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.months}
        onChange={handleChange('months')}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu,
          },
        }}
        helperText="Month looking to book"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
      >
        {months.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

**SubmitButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


export default function ContainedButtons(props) {

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled = {!props.isEnabled} type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: how are you using this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to move your components you can take the state handler out of infoForm.js

move this code to app.js and change the handler name to "handleChangeForm" (optional name)

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    months: ''
  });

  const handleChangeForm = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

then you can use the handler and the values in infoForm as properties like this:

```
 <Form values={values} handleChangeForm={handleChangeForm}/>
```

also you need to send to your button component the values as properties

Inside form component you should destructure the props like this:

```
  const { values, handleChangeForm } = props;

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off"> .....
```

onChange event example inside form

```
onChange={handleChangeForm("name")}
```

Finally you have the values connected to your buttom component and you can use a function
like this

```
  const onClickBtn = () => {
    console.log(props.values);
  };
```

when button is clicked

```
  <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        disabled={!props.isEnabled}
        type="submit"
        onClick={onClickBtn}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
```

Comment: I really like this solution but I am getting the following error:
`./src/Components/InfoForm.js
  Line 191:  'props' is not defined`

Comment: I tried adding it as an argument like ` function Form(props)`  but then I get another error saying:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Form
C:/Users/dfriedl/Desktop/impulse-ink/src/Components/InfoForm.js:200
  197 | id="outlined-name"
  198 | label="Name"
  199 | className={classes.textField}
> 200 | value={values.name}
      `

Comment: Inside infoForm.js after adding props as an argument did you declared values like "const { values, handleChangeForm } = props"? Also inside app.js dont forget to send the props to the form tag.  <Form values={values} handleChangeForm={handleChangeForm}/> you can use a console.log(props) inside infoForms.js to ser what is receiving

Comment: First off I just want to say thank you much. It is working perfectly. The issue was that I placed the code on the form tag in InfoForm instead of on the Form tag in App.js.

Second, I see that you work at Softtek in Monterrey. I used to work at Sterling Talent Solutions in Atlanta and had the opportunity to work with some of your guys. They were so smart and helpful, like you. Gracias por todo amigo!