# How to get TextField(Material-UI) value from hook react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks, use-ref

I using Material-UI with react, have component like:

```
const UserDetail = (props: ListDetailProps) => {
    const oldpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const newpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const againpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const handlePasswordChange = async () => {
        console.log(newpassword.current?.value)    //expect the password value but undefined get
        console.log(againpassword.current?.value)  //expect the password value but undefined get
    }
    return (<>
        <p>old password: <TextField ref={oldpassword} label="old password" type="password" /></p>
        <p>new password: <TextField ref={newpassword} label="new password" type="password" /></p>
        <p>new password: <TextField ref={againpassword} label="new password again" type="password" /></p>
        <button onClick={handlePasswordChange}>submit</button>
    </>
    )
}
```

I want get the value of ref TextField but get undefined.
How to get the value of ref TextField?

I have read the answer of :
[React: How to get values from Material-UI TextField components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641235/react-how-to-get-values-from-material-ui-textfield-components),

But this answer for Form button, if I do not have form how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `inputRef` instead of `ref`. 
That is because `inputRef` will pass a ref to the input element.

```
const UserDetail = (props: ListDetailProps) => {
    const oldpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const newpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const againpassword = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
    const handlePasswordChange = async () => {
        console.log(newpassword.current?.value)    //expect the password value but undefined get
        console.log(againpassword.current?.value)  //expect the password value but undefined get
    }
    return (<>
        <p>old password: <TextField inputRef={oldpassword} label="old password" type="password" /></p>
        <p>new password: <TextField inputRef={newpassword} label="new password" type="password" /></p>
        <p>new password: <TextField inputRef={againpassword} label="new password again" type="password" /></p>
        <button onClick={handlePasswordChange}>submit</button>
    </>
    )
}
```

You can refer to [material-ui TextField API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)